# Where I can find Envelope Detector Block in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, modulation

Where I can find Envelope Detector blocks in Simulink like that 2 below:

[image: envelope detector block 1]

[image: envelope detector block 2]

Comment: Looks like a subsystem put together by whoever created the model that you have given a snapshot of rather than a library block.  Why not ask them?  There is an [Envelope Detection](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/examples/envelope-detection.html) example in the doc if you want to see how to do it.

Comment: any idea how to simulate in simulink that envelope detector on first picture? how to simulate resistor, diode and capacitor in simulink ?

Comment: You can either implement the individual differential equations for the RLC components using appropriate integrators and gains, or use something like [Simscape Electrical](https://www.mathworks.com/products/simscape-electrical.html) if you have access to it.